# Play youtube videos Fullscreen webview crash

Tags: android, webview, youtube, fullscreen

I am trying to play videos Fullscreen on youtube but i cannot
One user sent me the following report

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.view.ViewGroup.addViewInner(ViewGroup.java:3377)
at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3249)
at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3225)
at android.webkit.HTML5VideoFullscreen.enterFullscreen(HTML5VideoFullscreen.java:253)
at android.webkit.HTML5VideoView.enterFullscreenVideoState(HTML5VideoView.java:527)
at android.webkit.HTML5VideoViewProxy$VideoPlayer.enterFullscreenVideo(HTML5VideoViewProxy.java:180)
at android.webkit.HTML5VideoViewProxy.handleMessage(HTML5VideoViewProxy.java:461)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4838)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:841)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:608)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

The code i use :

```
              web.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
              web.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
              web.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
              web.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
              web.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);


              web.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient(){
                  @Override
                    public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int newProgress) {          
                        super.onProgressChanged(view, newProgress);
                         pgb.setProgress(newProgress);
                      }     

                  @Override
                  public View getVideoLoadingProgressView() { 
                    FrameLayout frameLayout = new FrameLayout(MainActivity.this);    
                    frameLayout.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams( LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,    
                   LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
                    return frameLayout;
                  }
              });

              web.loadUrl("http://www.youtube.com");
```

I just want to make me understand how to do it.

Comment: I think the problem is on adding FrameLayout View why not use Actionbar Interminate Progress or Try to put a progress bar in the xml layout and set it's visibilty once the page is loaded and hide it when the progress is equal to 100

Comment: if you think that you found a solution please post it as answer. Thank you! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using the actionbarcompat hence I'm following the UI guidelines here

webview_layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Main.class

```
public class Main extends ActionBarActivity{

    private WebView mWebView;
    private String url;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        supportRequestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS);
        setContentView(R.layout.webview_layout);

        url="http://example.com";   

         getSupportActionBar();
         getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
         getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
         getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
         getSupportActionBar().setTitle("TITLE HERE");

        mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        mWebView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        mWebView.getSettings().setAppCacheMaxSize(1024*1024*8);
        mWebView.getSettings().setAppCachePath(""+this.getCacheDir());
        mWebView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true); 
        mWebView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_DEFAULT);    
        mWebView.loadUrl(url);
        mWebView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());

        mWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
            public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress) {
                super.onProgressChanged(view, progress);
                setSupportProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility((progress == 100)?false:true);
            } 
            public void onReceivedTitle(WebView view, String title) {
                super.onReceivedTitle(view, title);
                CharSequence notavail = "Webpage not available";

            }
        }); 
    }

    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && mWebView.canGoBack()) {
            mWebView.goBack();
            return true;
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
    private class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {

      public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
          view.loadUrl(url);
          return true;
      }
    }

}
```

Please free to ask if theirs anything that is not quite clear.
Thanks Hope it will help you, don't forget to vote up

Comment: Thank you it works using actionbar but i would like something more simle. Just like default browser which open gallery for fullscreen video. Perfect work by the way.